# Making a view non focusable

Tags: android-listview, android

I have a list view which uses two different row layouts.
One is to display a date header and another is to display a set of tasks for that date.
I do not want to Date headers to be highlighted, when the user
touches it. That is, I do not want the background of the view containing the date header to change in any way.

I have done the following as of now :

```
v.setEnabled(false);
v.setClickable(false);
v.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

where v is the view inflated from the layout containing the date header.

The original background of view is white, when it is not in touch with the user's finger.
Initially, the date header view would have a blue background on touch.
After the above code, the background is now grey.
I do not want the background to change from white even on touch .

Comment: If you want the background to be white all the time regardless of press states, you can always set background to `@color/white` in xml.

Answer (score 0):

You should override the [`isEnabled(int position)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#isEnabled%28int%29) method in your custom adapter. From the official API page:

> Returns true if the item at the specified position is not a separator. (A separator is a
>   non-selectable, non-clickable item). The result is unspecified if position is invalid. An
>   ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException should be thrown in that case for fast failure.